# Is position:absolute; left:-10000px; better than display:none;?

Tags: css

I have seen people set an element's style to:

```
element{
    position:absolute;
    left:-10000px;
}
```

rather than setting:

```
element{
    display:none;
}
```

Does the first method have better browser support, or why do they do it that way?

Comment: they? who are "they"? IMHO if attribute `display` exists, is for avoid such things as that.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

An element whose [display](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/display) style property is `none` cannot be [measured](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Determining_the_dimensions_of_elements). Properties like [offsetWidth](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.offsetWidth) and [offsetHeight](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.offsetHeight) will always return `0` in that case.

On the other hand, an element that's visible but displaced outside the document area can be measured. So, if you want to hide an element but still be able to determine its width and height, the first solution is the way to go.

Comment: What about visibility:hidden;? Why don't people use that?

Comment: @inquisitive_web_developer that will make the other elements flow around the area the hidden element is supposed to be

Comment: @inquisitive, an element with `visibility: hidden` still takes space in the layout.

Comment: Okay, it makes sense now. Thanks!

Comment: That is not the main purpose of this workaround but for screen readers http://webaim.org/blog/hiding-content-for-screen-readers/

Comment: I wish all the geniuses who make web frameworks would read your answer

Answer (score 0):

I think that is a solution to resolve an IE bug where an element hidden within another element that is hidden, displays, instead of being hidden.

I would use display: none unless you have are having browser issues or another reason that forces you not to.

Answer (score 0):

It's better for SEO and accessibility, since screen reasers will read text with negative offsets. Also, text search within browsers (Ctrl-F) works the same way.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to target your webpage for those with screen readers or text-only browsers, it's better to have display:none along with the media type, such as aural, braille, emboss, and tty that don't interpret images at all, but displays alternate text instead. Screen readers and text browsers can still read anything that's in an element with absolute positioning set to 1000 pixels to the left.

Here's an example of how I correctly set the elements to not to be displayed to screen readers and text browsers. This is in CSS:

```
@media handheld,print,projection,screen,tv
{
    #header h1
    {
        display: none;
    }
}

@media aural,braille,emboss,tty
{
    #header #m1,
    #menu li span,
    table thead th span,
    .submenu span
    {
        display: none;
    }
}

...
```

HTML:

```
...

    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="header">
            <h1>Grayson Peddie's Home Automation Interface</h1>
            <div id="m1">
                <img src="Images/MarqueeHeader/remotecontrol.jpg" alt=""
                    onmouseover="ShowHeaderToolTip('remotecontrol')"
                    onmouseout="HideHeaderToolTip('remotecontrol')" />
                <img src="Images/MarqueeHeader/doorsensor.jpg" alt=""
                    onmouseover="ShowHeaderToolTip('doorsensor')"
                    onmouseout="HideHeaderToolTip('doorsensor')" />
                <img src="Images/MarqueeHeader/lampmodule.jpg" alt=""
                    onmouseover="ShowHeaderToolTip('lampmodule')"
                    onmouseout="HideHeaderToolTip('lampmodule')" />
                <img src="Images/MarqueeHeader/floorlamp.jpg" alt=""
                    onmouseover="ShowHeaderToolTip('floorlamp')"
                    onmouseout="HideHeaderToolTip('floorlamp')" />
                <img src="Images/MarqueeHeader/Insteon.jpg" alt=""
                    onmouseover="ShowHeaderToolTip('insteon')"
                    onmouseout="HideHeaderToolTip('insteon')" />
                <img src="Images/MarqueeHeader/remotecontrol.jpg" alt=""
                    onmouseover="ShowHeaderToolTip('remotecontrol')"
                    onmouseout="HideHeaderToolTip('remotecontrol')" />
                <img src="Images/MarqueeHeader/doorsensor.jpg" alt=""
                    onmouseover="ShowHeaderToolTip('doorsensor')"
                    onmouseout="HideHeaderToolTip('doorsensor')" />
                <img src="Images/MarqueeHeader/lampmodule.jpg" alt=""
                    onmouseover="ShowHeaderToolTip('lampmodule')"
                    onmouseout="HideHeaderToolTip('lampmodule')" />
                <img src="Images/MarqueeHeader/floorlamp.jpg" alt=""
                    onmouseover="ShowHeaderToolTip('floorlamp')"
                    onmouseout="HideHeaderToolTip('floorlamp')" />
                <img src="Images/MarqueeHeader/Insteon.jpg" alt=""
                    onmouseover="ShowHeaderToolTip('insteon')"
                    onmouseout="HideHeaderToolTip('insteon')" />
                <img src="Images/MarqueeHeader/remotecontrol.jpg" alt=""
                    onmouseover="ShowHeaderToolTip('remotecontrol')"
                    onmouseout="HideHeaderToolTip('remotecontrol')" />
            </div>
            <ul id="menu">
                <li>
                    <span>Home</span>
                    <a href="javascript:SwitchContent('home')">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <span>Timers</span>
                    <a href="javascript:SwitchContent('timers')">Timers</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <span>Admin</span>
                    <a href="javascript:SwitchContent('admin')">Admin</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>

...
```

I hope this helps.

The span tag is used for making a shadow with absolute positioning and z-index.

Comment: The problem none of the current available screen readers supports aural http://www.cactusflower.org/why-screen-readers-dont-support-aural-css